# Error in installing tidyverse in Windows: installation had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, installation, tidyverse

I'm trying to install tidyverse package in R in Windows. However, I get the error message:

```
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

I couldn't find solutions for this problem on Windows, only for Ubuntu.
The entire installation message is described below:

```
  
    WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘processx’, ‘highr’, ‘xfun’, ‘tinytex’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘vctrs’, ‘gargle’, ‘rematch2’, ‘scales’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘callr’, ‘knitr’, ‘rmarkdown’, ‘broom’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘dplyr’, ‘dtplyr’, ‘forcats’, ‘googledrive’, ‘googlesheets4’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘haven’, ‘hms’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘lubridate’, ‘magrittr’, ‘modelr’, ‘pillar’, ‘readr’, ‘reprex’, ‘rlang’, ‘rvest’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyr’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
              binary source needs_compilation
processx       3.4.2  3.5.2              TRUE
highr            0.8    0.9             FALSE
xfun            0.13   0.23             FALSE
tinytex         0.22   0.32             FALSE
lifecycle      0.2.0  1.0.0             FALSE
tidyselect     1.0.0  1.1.1             FALSE
vctrs          0.2.4  0.3.8              TRUE
gargle         0.4.0  1.1.0             FALSE
rematch2       2.1.0  2.1.2             FALSE
scales         1.1.0  1.1.1             FALSE
ellipsis       0.3.0  0.3.2              TRUE
callr          3.4.3  3.7.0             FALSE
knitr           1.28   1.33             FALSE
rmarkdown        2.1    2.9             FALSE
broom          0.5.6  0.7.7             FALSE
dbplyr         1.4.3  2.1.1             FALSE
dplyr          0.8.5  1.0.6              TRUE
dtplyr         1.0.1  1.1.0             FALSE
forcats        0.5.0  0.5.1             FALSE
googledrive    1.0.0  1.0.1             FALSE
googlesheets4  0.1.1  0.3.0             FALSE
ggplot2        3.3.0  3.3.3             FALSE
haven          2.2.0  2.4.1              TRUE
hms            0.5.3  1.1.0             FALSE
jsonlite       1.6.1  1.7.2              TRUE
lubridate      1.7.8 1.7.10              TRUE
magrittr         1.5  2.0.1             FALSE
modelr         0.1.6  0.1.8             FALSE
pillar         1.4.3  1.6.1             FALSE
readr          1.3.1  1.4.0              TRUE
reprex         0.3.0  2.0.0             FALSE
rlang          0.4.5 0.4.11              TRUE
rvest          0.3.5  1.0.0             FALSE
tibble         3.0.1  3.1.2              TRUE
tidyr          1.0.2  1.1.3              TRUE
tidyverse      1.3.0  1.3.1             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/processx_3.4.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 425981 bytes (415 KB)
downloaded 415 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/vctrs_0.2.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1018801 bytes (994 KB)
downloaded 994 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/ellipsis_0.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 44220 bytes (43 KB)
downloaded 43 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/dplyr_0.8.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3256479 bytes (3.1 MB)
downloaded 3.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/haven_2.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1050152 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/jsonlite_1.6.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1164207 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/lubridate_1.7.8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1583751 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/readr_1.3.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1588558 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/rlang_0.4.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1115838 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/tibble_3.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 407904 bytes (398 KB)
downloaded 398 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/tidyr_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1297802 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

package ‘processx’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘ellipsis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘haven’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘jsonlite’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘lubridate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘readr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tibble’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tidyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\u006743\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0cmfHs\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘highr’, ‘xfun’, ‘tinytex’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘gargle’, ‘rematch2’, ‘scales’, ‘callr’, ‘knitr’, ‘rmarkdown’, ‘broom’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘dtplyr’, ‘forcats’, ‘googledrive’, ‘googlesheets4’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘hms’, ‘magrittr’, ‘modelr’, ‘pillar’, ‘reprex’, ‘rvest’, ‘tidyverse’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/highr_0.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 15188 bytes (14 KB)
downloaded 14 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xfun_0.23.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 111696 bytes (109 KB)
downloaded 109 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tinytex_0.32.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 30014 bytes (29 KB)
downloaded 29 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 83389 bytes (81 KB)
downloaded 81 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyselect_1.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 92088 bytes (89 KB)
downloaded 89 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gargle_1.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 295629 bytes (288 KB)
downloaded 288 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rematch2_2.1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 13366 bytes (13 KB)
downloaded 13 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/scales_1.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 515201 bytes (503 KB)
downloaded 503 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/callr_3.7.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 74518 bytes (72 KB)
downloaded 72 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/knitr_1.33.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 892378 bytes (871 KB)
downloaded 871 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rmarkdown_2.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3246617 bytes (3.1 MB)
downloaded 3.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/broom_0.7.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 632928 bytes (618 KB)
downloaded 618 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dbplyr_2.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 581845 bytes (568 KB)
downloaded 568 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dtplyr_1.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 111895 bytes (109 KB)
downloaded 109 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/forcats_0.5.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 258301 bytes (252 KB)
downloaded 252 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/googledrive_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1808539 bytes (1.7 MB)
downloaded 1.7 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/googlesheets4_0.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 435126 bytes (424 KB)
downloaded 424 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.3.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3058840 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/hms_1.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 43142 bytes (42 KB)
downloaded 42 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/magrittr_2.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 265580 bytes (259 KB)
downloaded 259 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/modelr_0.1.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 121333 bytes (118 KB)
downloaded 118 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/pillar_1.6.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1111747 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/reprex_2.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1087170 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rvest_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 94134 bytes (91 KB)
downloaded 91 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 702779 bytes (686 KB)
downloaded 686 KB

* installing *source* package 'xfun' ...
** package 'xfun' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'xfun'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/xfun'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xfun’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/lifecycle'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'tidyselect' ...
** package 'tidyselect' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.6 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'tidyselect'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tidyselect'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyselect’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'gargle' ...
** package 'gargle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.9 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'gargle'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/gargle'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gargle’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'rematch2' ...
** package 'rematch2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'lifecycle'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'rematch2'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rematch2'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rematch2’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'callr' ...
** package 'callr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'processx' 3.4.2 is being loaded, but >= 3.5.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'callr'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/callr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'broom' ...
** package 'broom' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'dplyr' 0.8.5 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'broom'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/broom'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'magrittr' ...
** package 'magrittr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'magrittr'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/magrittr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘magrittr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'xfun' is not available for package 'highr'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/highr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘highr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'xfun' is not available for package 'tinytex'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tinytex'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tinytex’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'scales'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/scales'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'lifecycle', 'magrittr', 'tidyselect' are not available for package 'dbplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/dbplyr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'lifecycle', 'tidyselect' are not available for package 'dtplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/dtplyr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dtplyr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'magrittr' is not available for package 'forcats'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/forcats'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘forcats’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'gargle', 'magrittr' are not available for package 'googledrive'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/googledrive'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googledrive’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'hms'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/hms'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hms’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'broom', 'magrittr', 'tidyselect' are not available for package 'modelr'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/modelr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘modelr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'pillar'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/pillar'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'lifecycle', 'magrittr' are not available for package 'rvest'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rvest'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'highr', 'xfun' are not available for package 'knitr'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/knitr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'gargle', 'googledrive', 'lifecycle', 'magrittr', 'rematch2' are not available for package 'googlesheets4'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/googlesheets4'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googlesheets4’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'scales' is not available for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/ggplot2'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'knitr', 'tinytex', 'xfun' are not available for package 'rmarkdown'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: failed to lock directory 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5' for modifying
Try removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/00LOCK-reprex'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘reprex’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'broom', 'dbplyr', 'dtplyr', 'forcats', 'googledrive', 'googlesheets4', 'ggplot2', 'hms', 'magrittr', 'modelr', 'pillar', 'reprex', 'rvest' are not available for package 'tidyverse'
* removing 'C:/Users/u006743/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tidyverse'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: First, restart R and make sure nothing is loaded. Then when you run `install.packages("tidyverse")` and it asks you if you want to install newer packages from source, be sure to say "No" rather than "Yes."

Comment: Are you also still running R 3.5? if not, this is probably a good time to update to the latest version of R.

Comment: Thanks! I have to use R 3.5 because this is a computer from my firm. However, I'm not seeing this question in the installation process.

Comment: If you aren't setting a message, then try `install.packages("tidyverse", type="binary")` to be explicit. If that doesn't work you're going to have to contact your IT people to see if they can install things for you.

Comment: Thanks! The installation worked with this command! (I still didn't receive the question though)